# How to combine data from two API endpoints?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a component which has a dropdown. Based on what's selected in dropdown - the component displays additional information, by issuing another HTTP request.

If nothing is selected (first time component is displayed), then component should selected first one from the list

I have tried to subscribe to API response, but then I need to make nested API call, which I know is a bad practice...

```js
ngOnInit() {
 this.myService.getSelectedUnit(this.id).subscribe(selectedUnit => {
   this.myService.getAllUnits().subscribe(units => {

    if (!selectedUnit) {
      selectedUnit = units[0];
    }

      this.myService.getUnitData(selectedUnit).subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
      });

   });

});

}
```

I would like to avoid nesting the api calls and integrate it into one observable sequence.